# Xamarin not including resource folder on build

Tags: c#, xamarin, build, compiler-errors

Yo,

When I build my C# program, one of my folders, and it's .txt file come across with the rest of the resources (that came with the template/library I'm using), but no other folders and the .png files in them will come.

I try to make new files, and folders, with names that aren't used elsewhere, I add them to the project, clean the build, and rebuild. I check the bin/debug folder, and it doesn't come across.

HELP! AND... stuff... yea

Notes:

- With help from other programmers, we know it isn't to do with the code that I'm writing. The issue stands independent of my code.
- It was working earlier with a folder, and the (at the time) 1 .png file. But after another .png was added, that file didn't work. And after a couple more builds, the the .png file stopped importing across. I've been hard coding to another folder which holds the resources until this gets fixed.
- **EDIT**: - Can confirm it is not the file path length. I've moved the project to a new folder where the file path is shorter

Comment: Hey, most of the resources you will find inside the bin folder are mostly the server side codes and encrypted inside binaries. For resources, images, views these components are not compiled. `It doesn't mean` that what you see outside the bin folder will be copied inside it.`

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow. So resources (including images) are not compiled (makes sense, since it's not code) But how do I get the images I need to access come across as part of the build? Do I need to change the format, or perhaps change a setting so the folder gets forced to copy.
I still don't get why one folder copies across fine (and with it's components!) while the other does not.

Comment: Images format should not be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Properties of the file (Visual Studio Properties: right click on the file in the Solution Explorer, select Properties) set '**Build Action**' to '**Content**' and '**Copy to Output Directory**' to '**Copy always**' or 'Copy if newer'.

The file and the project folder containing the file will then be part of the build output, usually in bin\Debug\ or bin\Release.

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks heaps. I feel a bit smarter now :)
Bless ya